# Splot (contour, view map) and plot on same graph

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot two overlaying graphs.

The first is a simple x-y points plot:

```
plot myfile u 1:2
```

The second is a contour plot at level 0, which I can plot with the
following commands:

```
set contour
unset surface
set view map
set cntrparam levels discrete 0
splot a0 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*x**2 + a4*x*y + a5*y**2 + a6*x**3 + a7*x**2*y + a8*x*y**2 + a9*y**3
```

`a0`-`a9` are constants

Both use the same xrange and yrange.

How can I plot them both in the same graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat tricky one.  You can write the contours to a file using

*untested*

```
set table 'datafile'
set contour
#contour options
splot ... with contours
unset table
```

Then you can plot that data with lines:

```
set term ...
set output ...
set view map
splot myfile u 1:2:(0.0), 'datafile'  u 1:2:3 w lines
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I had to change was `splot my file 1:2:(0.0)`

Comment: @mgilson Perhaps you can provide a concrete example. I was trying to plot (to plot a point) and splot (to plot an implicit function) on the same set of axes. I tried this:

    set multiplot; set lmargin 10; set rmargin 2; set size 1,1; set origin 0,0; splot x*y-1; set xrange [GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX]; set yrange [GPVAL_Y_MIN:GPVAL_Y_MAX]; plot "<echo '0 0'"; unset multiplot

but two sets of axes are drawn, one larger than the other.

Comment: @DavidDoria -- Are you plotting only a single point?  If so, you can accomplish that via `set label`

Comment: @mgilson That will actually work for what I'm trying to do now, thanks. However it still seems reasonable to want to combine a plot and splot on one set of axes for future users :)

Comment: @DavidDoria -- This answer is about combining a splot with a splot which makes a lot of sense.  However, combining a `plot` and a `splot` is a little more tricky to do in general.  e.g. how do you combine a plot (necessarily confined in the x-y plane) with a `splot` which has a viewing angle looking at the y-z plane?  Then you need to know more about what the user really wants the plot to look like to give a solid answer.

Comment: To get this to work for my implicit function, I need `set contour base` and `splot ...` (without `with contours`). http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-300003.7